# How to use -I backend with Mdb-tools 0.7~rc1-4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ms-access, ubuntu-11.10

I want to convert ms-access database to sql via mdbtools.
on ubuntu 11.10 32bit with mdbtools 0.5.99.0.6pre1.0.20051109-7.1 when i am using mdbtools -I backend is working fine. i.e. i got file with Insert statement.
but on ubuntu 12.04lts 64bit, mdbtools, 0.7~rc1-4  i am not able to convert mdb file into sql file.

my syntax is :
 mdb-tools -I   >

please let me know any correction is needed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

`mdb-tools -I access` shuld work

Supported backends are: `access`, `sybase`, `oracle`, `postgres`, `mysql`